# Incongruent solutions of $c \cdot x^d \equiv r \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have been looking at congruences of the form $c\cdot x^d \equiv r \pmod p$, where $r$ is a primitive root of $p$, and $d | \phi(p)=p-1$. Looking at empirical evidence for a few instances I have conjectured that there are $\frac{p-1}{d}$ incongruent values for $c$ such that such congruences have solutions.

However, I am not able to justify it with a proof. For instance, for $c \cdot x^2 \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$, $c$ could be any of the $S=\{2,6,7,8,10\}$. Note $6$ is a primitive root of $11$ and $2|10$ and $10/2=5=|S|$.

Am I onto something? Is this true in general regardless of whether $r$ is a primitive root or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ cx^d\equiv r\pmod{p}\ $, where $\ d\,|\,p-1\ $then
$$
\big(rc^{-1}\big)^\frac{p-1}{d}\equiv x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\ .
$$
The polynomial $\ x^\frac{p-1}{d}-1\ $ has exactly $\ \frac{p-1}{d}\ $ roots in $\ \mathbb{Z}_p\ $, which can be enumerated as $\ \rho^{jd}\ $ for $\ j=0,1,\dots,\frac{p-1}{d}-1\ $, where $\ \rho\ $ is a primitive root mod $\ p\ $. Thus, for any $\ r\not\equiv0\pmod{p}\ $, regardless of whether or not it's a primitive root, the equation will have a solution if and only if $\ c\ $ is one of the $\ \frac{p-1}{d}\ $ distinct residues $\ r\rho^{-jd}\ $.

Answer (score 0):

As $r$ is a primitive root, we can write $c=r^k$ for some $0\leq k\leq p-1$ (as obviously $c\neq0$), so it suffices to count the number of such $k$'s. Now the equation becomes $x^d\equiv r^{1-k}\pmod p$, and this has a solution exactly when $d|1-k$. As we have $p-1$ "continuous" possible values of $k$ and $d|p-1$, the result now follows.